# Got ValueErrror: too many values to unpack when trying to use train_test_split from scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, iterable-unpacking

`**valueerrror:** too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I'm getting this error while splitting my `.csv` mnist dataset.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/digit_svm.csv")
x = df.iloc[:,1:784].values
y = df.iloc[:,0].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
(x_train,x_test), (y_train,y_test) = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
```

the error is on the last line. it shows this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-832086f0fd65> in <module>()
----> 1 (x_train,x_test), (y_train,y_test) =  train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: `df` is a dataframe (like a grid table). How do you expect that to split  your data to train and test for you? I think you meant to do it like this: `(x_train,x_test), (y_train,y_test) = train_test_split(df.iloc[:,-1], df['target'], test_size=0.2)`, where `df.iloc[:,-1]` is all columns of csv file except last column, and `df['target']` is your last column which is `y` (column name:`target`). You should change these two based on your data.

Comment: ah thank you for your help! i tried but it still shows error. i did it in the edited way above but im getting error

Comment: Remove parentheses. like:  `x_train,x_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2)`

Answer (score 0):

`train_test_split` split each input into 2 parts & returns them. It can take dataframe as input.

In case of one input, say x:

```
 x_train, x_test = train_test_split(x, test_size=0.2)
```

In your case, there are 2 inputs `x` , `y`. hence it returns 4 objects.

```
 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
```

but the main issue here is with unpacking, refer [here](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/) to know how it works with examples.

Comment: Ah that helped me understand the err! Thank you!